# How to get DateTime month in  upper case?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I am using the following to format a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime CusDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
string Date = CusDate.ToString("ddMMMyyyy");
```

I am getting the format such that "Nov" is not in upper case:

```
04Nov2011
```

But I want the format of "Nov" in capital letters, like this:

```
04NOV2011
```

This is because I am downloading a file from a website programatically which is in this format.

Comment: but those variable names :p

https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just do the string ToUpper():

```
    DateTime CusDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    string Date = CusDate.ToString("ddMMMyyyy").ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 2):

After you're done with the toString...

```
string date = date.ToUpper();
```

Comment: Simpler to add the `.ToUpper()` call after the `.ToString("ddMMMyyyy")` call, I think.  Not sure if there's any actual under-the-hood differences though.

Comment: The compiler will probably optimise it anyway.

Comment: True enough.  Might be interesting to compare the MSIL between the two, but for all intents and purposes it's fine either way.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`String.ToUpper()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewdd6aed.aspx) method:

```
DateTime CusDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
string Date = CusDate.ToString("ddMMMyyyy").ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the string to upper case (won't affect the numbers):

```
DateTime CusDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
string Date = CusDate.ToString("ddMMMyyyy").ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// project reference to System.Globalization
using System.Globalization;

// example uses properties of an en-US DateTimeFormatInfo object
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat;

// date time string to format
"2018-09-07 00:00:00".ToString("MMMM d, yyy", dtfi).ToUpper());

// result
SEPTEMBER 7, 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to call `ToUpper()` directly, unless you never plan to expand your app to other countries. In a lot of languages, all uppercase doesn't really make sense, so I'd suggest checking locale and only apply `ToUpper()` for a "white list" which would include all `en-*` codes.